# how to return a list element c++

Tags: c++

I have this:

```
Item findItem(std::string name)
    {
        for(std::list<Item*>::iterator it = listItem.begin(); it != listItem.end(); it++)
        {        
            if((*it)->name() == name){
                return ___;
            }   
        }

    }
```

how can I return correctly the element?

Comment: Hopefully you return something when the search does not find anything otherwise you have undefined behavior.

Comment: @JLev Are you sure it's `*it`, not `**it`?

Comment: A list of pointers is unusual. If these are *owning* pointers to dynamically allocated items, i.e. that at some point a `delete` expression is executed for each pointer in the list, then do consider replacing pointers to items with just items. A list of items.

Comment: You're mixing terms. The element is an `Item*`, but the function returns `Item`. Which is it that you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return **it;
```

is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

- `it` is the iterator
- `*it` is the `Item*`, the element of the container that `it` is referring to at the moment
- `**it` is the actual `Item` you presumably want to return a copy of

Don't forget to throw an exception or something if the element wasn't found! Reaching the end of a function that returns something other than `void`, without returning something other than `void`, imbues your program with undefined behaviour (unless the function is `main`, in which case `return 0` is assumed).

Also, have a think about whether you *really* need/want to store pointers; consider a `std::list<Item>` instead. If you stick with the pointers, check to ensure that you are managing their lifetime properly. When you find out that you're not, switch to smart pointers. Then consider again whether you *really* need/want to store pointers.